# If 3137 753 is mutiplied out, what is the units' digit (one's place ) in the final product? Show work and explain you answer. Think patterns.

Tags: geometry

3137 753 zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxxxxxzxxxxxxx

Comment: Don't spam. Put the question in the body.

Comment: The `show work` part is missing. And the `geometry` tag is unwarranted.

Comment: Don't spam George. Instead, apply what you have done and re edit the tags.

Comment: @Frank I am a great believer in giving posters the chance to correct their own missteps, first.

Comment: Think about multiplication by hand.  Do you know how to do that? Where does the units digit of the product come from?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you want geometry, so the best geometric idea I have (its not geometric at all) is given by the following:

Consider multiplying two arbitrary numbers and wishing to find the last digit (for this example, I will be using $4321\times123$):

$$(1x^0+2x^1+3x^2+4x^3)\times(3x^0+2x^1+x^2)\tag{$x=10$}$$

The ones place is given as the $x^0$ term.  Anyway, multiplying should be done as follows:

[image]

And, well, we want the $x^0$ term, given by the top left box.  In other words, all we have to do is multiply the $x^0$ terms to get the last digit:

$$\operatorname{last digit}((1x^0+2x^1+3x^2+4x^3)\times(3x^0+2x^1+x^2))=1\times3=3$$

If we wanted the next digit, we simply find all of the $1$'s in the table above and add them up together.  You can do this for any general $n$'th digit.

---

As a neat little last remark, this method works for base $x$ numbers, expanded as polynomials of $x$, and finding the $n$th coefficient term to find the resulting $n$th last digit.

Comment: +1 for an original way to present $4321 \cdot 123 = (1 + 4320) \cdot (3 + 120)$ $= 1 \cdot 3 + 10 \cdot (1 \cdot 12 + 432 \cdot 3) + 100 \cdot (432 \cdot 12)$.

Comment: @dxiv $\color{white}{\text{Oh, many backwards oopsies}}$ ;)  I thought of it in response to a question on how to multiply factors over at matheducators.SE